# Unable to publish in pubsub xmpp

Tags: xmpp, publish-subscribe, ejabberd

i sent the following stanza to ejabbers server after creating a node "test1_node1"

```
<iq id="publish1" to="pubsub.oomaxmpp.com" type="get" from="admin@oomaxmpp.com/1697575709134613774110793">
<pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub">
<publish node="test_node1"><item id="qwert12345">
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<title>*publish*</title>
<summary>*1234567890*</summary>
<published>2003-12-13T18:30:02Z</published>
<updated>2003-12-13T18:30:02Z</updated>
</entry>
</item>
</publish>
</pubsub>
</iq>
```

but i get an error result with following stanza,

```
<iq id="publish1" xml:lang="en" type="error" to="admin@oomaxmpp.com/1697575709134613774110793" from="pubsub.oomaxmpp.com">
<pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub"><publish node="test_node1">
<item id="qwert12345"><entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<title>*publish*</title>
<summary>*1234567890*</summary>
<published>2003-12-13T18:30:02Z</published>
<updated>2003-12-13T18:30:02Z</updated>
</entry>
</item>
</publish>
</pubsub>
<error code="501" type="cancel"><feature-not-implemented xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
</error>
</iq>
```

i dont understand,if feature was not implemented how nodes were created?
Why cant i publish?

Comment: {mod_pubsub,   [ % requires mod_caps
                  {access_createnode, pubsub_createnode},
                  {pep_sendlast_offline, false},
                  {last_item_cache, false},
                  %%{plugins, ["default", "pep"]}
                  {plugins, ["flat", "hometree", "pep"]}  % pep requires mod_caps
                 ]},

Comment: ejabberd configuration module for pubsub

Comment: Is your problem solved by enabling pubsub in ejabberd configuration ?

Comment: yes its solved....but i guess you have to enable mod_caps too....